# Take picture from camera in samsung device

Tags: android, android-layout

I am facing one problem. In my application profile picture is there, if I tap the picture one popup will display. In that popup take photo and image from gallery button is there. if I set an image from gallery its working fine but take picture from camera is working fine only in Nexus and htc device not in Samsung device, because camera orientation changes from landscape to portrait(in Samsung default camera is landscape mode but my application is fixed as portrait mode.) so my layout goes down half of the screen.

I added those lines in manifest

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
android:configChanges="locale|touchscreen|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|keyboardHidden"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|stateUnchanged|adjustPan"
```

Comment: Your image probably has exif and you should rotate it manually accordingly to it

Comment: I don't want image rotation my query is my whole layout goes down when orientation changes from landscape to portrait.